# Screen recording problem

Tags: screen, display-resolution

Can anybody help me? When I try to record my screen with any screen recorder, the final recording comes out just like it, compressed into a small square.

[image]

(This photo is a print of the final screen recording, the video is square, I tried several recorders, like OBS or simplecreenrecorder)

Comment: Are you interested in using FFmpeg? If so could you give me your screen dimensions and I can suggest a command line...